# three.js positioning texture on a model with many faces

Tags: json, three.js, textures, positioning

I am trying to show furniture i design and make on my website. So people can move it around and ultimately alter materials and colors. A configurator so to speak.

Here is what i got so far: http://www.wijmakenalles.nl/configurator.php

As you can see the texture on the table top has a repeat seam where is should not. 
I know i can move textures around tweaking uv's but as there are over 600 faces and over 900 uv's on the model it seems pointless to search for the corresponding face/uv's in the json file. It is not just a cube.
Here is the materials part of the json:
    {

```
"metadata" :
{
    "formatVersion" : 3.1,
    "generatedBy"   : "Blender 2.65 Exporter",
    "vertices"      : 1116,
    "faces"         : 647,
    "normals"       : 208,
    "colors"        : 0,
    "uvs"           : [972],
    "materials"     : 1,
    "morphTargets"  : 0,
    "bones"         : 0
},

"scale" : 1.000000,

"materials" : [ {
    "DbgColor" : 15658734,
    "DbgIndex" : 0,
    "DbgName" : "beton.001",
    "blending" : "NormalBlending",
    "colorAmbient" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
    "colorDiffuse" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
    "colorSpecular" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
    "depthTest" : true,
    "depthWrite" : true,
    "mapDiffuse" : "texturez_3914.jpg",
    "mapDiffuseRepeat" : [2, 2],
    "mapDiffuseWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
    "shading" : "Lambert",
    "specularCoef" : 50,
    "transparency" : 1.0,
    "transparent" : false,
    "vertexColors" : false
},

{
    "DbgColor" : 15658734,
    "DbgIndex" : 0,
    "DbgName" : "default",
    "vertexColors" : false
},

{
    "DbgColor" : 15597568,
    "DbgIndex" : 1,
    "DbgName" : "beton",
    "blending" : "NormalBlending",
    "colorAmbient" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
    "colorDiffuse" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
    "colorSpecular" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
    "depthTest" : true,
    "depthWrite" : true,
    "mapDiffuse" : "concrete.jpg",
    "mapDiffuseRepeat" : [1, 8],
    "shading" : "Lambert",
    "specularCoef" : 50,
    "transparency" : 1.0,
    "transparent" : false,
    "vertexColors" : false
},

{
    "DbgColor" : 15597568,
    "DbgIndex" : 1,
    "DbgName" : "beton",
    "blending" : "NormalBlending",
    "colorAmbient" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
    "colorDiffuse" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
    "colorSpecular" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
    "depthTest" : true,
    "depthWrite" : true,
    "mapDiffuse" : "concrete.jpg",
    "mapDiffuseRepeat" : [1, 8],
    "shading" : "Lambert",
    "specularCoef" : 50,
    "transparency" : 1.0,
    "transparent" : false,
    "vertexColors" : false
},

{
    "DbgColor" : 15597568,
    "DbgIndex" : 0,
    "DbgName" : "houtpaneel",
    "blending" : "NormalBlending",
    "colorAmbient" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
    "colorDiffuse" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
    "colorSpecular" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
    "depthTest" : true,
    "depthWrite" : true,
    "mapDiffuse" : "eikenorigineel.jpg",
    "mapDiffuseRepeat" : [0.01, 0.027],
    "mapDiffuseWrap" : ["norepeat", "norepeat"],
    "shading" : "Face",
    "specularCoef" : 50,
    "transparency" : 1.0,
    "transparent" : false,
    "vertexColors" : false
}],

"vertices" : [5.4625,-0.0032920.....etc.
```

And this is de loader code:

```
    // Load in the mesh and add it to the scene.
  var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
  loader.load( "json/eikenbetontafel.js", function(geo, materials){
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, material);
            mesh.position.set(-.45, 0, .18);
    scene.add(mesh);
  });
```

Hope someone can give me a direction to go, thanks

Comment: And the error in your code you are facing is..???

Comment: I noticed the mapDiffuseRepeatx was not quite accurate. Now the measurements of 1 tile corresponds with the table top it solves the problem.

Comment: Still, this feels like a work around that is just ok because there is just one face that realy matters here. Looking for something like offsetx and offsety to move a texture over a face.

Comment: @infinity Not sure what you mean. See my edits above.